# Apache caught SIGTERM, shutting down and port 80 using by perl procceses

Tags: apache-2.2, perl

Apache randomly shutdown and cant restart.
Port 80 used by perl processes.
When I kill processes which use port 80, apache can restart again.

log and results :

**tail -50 /var/log/httpd/error_log**

```
[Sat Jan 07 00:11:01 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

**ns1:/proc/15852# fuser -n tcp 80**

```
80/tcp:               6072 15849 15852
```

**ns1:/proc/15852# ls -l**

```
total 0
-r-------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 auxv
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:24 cmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 coredump_filter
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:37 cwd -> /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-2.11.5-all-languages
-r-------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:24 environ
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:37 exe -> /usr/bin/perl
dr-x------ 2 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:37 fd
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 io
-r-------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 limits
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 loginuid
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:37 maps
-rw------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 mem
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 mounts
-r-------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 mountstats
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 oom_adj
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 oom_score
lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:37 root -> /
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 schedstat
-r-------- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 smaps
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:24 stat
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 statm
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:24 status
dr-xr-xr-x 3 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 task
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 0 2012-01-07 00:30 wchan
```

**ns1:/proc/15852# /etc/init.d/httpd restart**

```
Stopping httpd:
Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/xxx/public_html] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/xxx/private_html] does not exist
[Sat Jan 07 00:48:37 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Jan 07 00:48:37 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

---

Randomly, I mean, Uncertain time, some times in night when server has very low traffic. Sometimes has more traffic.

I don't know other process are taking port 80 or apache still usign port 80. If other process are taking port 80, I want to know which proceses and why they taking. And how can I avoid this.

In question there is a proc directory ls result of process (pid number 15852). This process using port 80. Maybe it will help to recognize problem.

In **http error log** there is only line about this problem:

```
[Sat Jan 07 00:11:01 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

---- New edit, problem happend again. I try netstat command and in this case pid id 7574 ----

**netstat -tpnl | grep ":80" result :**

```
ns1:~# netstat -tpnl | grep ":80"
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7574/apache3 -k sta 

ns1:/proc/7574# more cmdline
/usr/sbin/apache3 -k start
ns1:/proc/7574# ls /usr/sbin/apache3
ls: cannot access /usr/sbin/apache3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Define "randomly", when does it shut down (and do you have the logs from one of those shutdowns)?  And why do you have other processes taking port 80?

Comment: Your fuser command doesnt indicate anything. Just because something is using a port, doesnt mean its bound to it for listening (which is the issue). Try `netstat -tpnl | grep ":80"` instead

Comment: `ns1:~# netstat -tpnl | grep ":80"` Here is result :

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7574/apache3 -k sta`

Comment: `ns1:/proc/7574# more cmdline` 
`/usr/sbin/apache3 -k start`
`ns1:/proc/7574# ls /usr/sbin/apache3`
`ls: cannot access /usr/sbin/apache3: No such file or directory`

Comment: That netstat comment shows that its apache3 listening on port 80, so its already running and this is why you cant start it again.

Comment: Yes, I know it Patrick. But I don't find a process named as "apache3". This is not in file system. And I want to know how apache replacing with apache3 ? And how can I stop this problem.